# Standards for dealing with older/previous ".bak" backup of config file before new edit

Tags: centos, backup, filenames

Assume I have a config file "foo.conf."  This file is rarely edited.  At some point in the BeforeTime(tm) it was edited and "foo.conf.bak" was created to save the previous state.  Now, I want to make an additional edit, and would like to make the current contents of "foo.conf" into "foo.conf.bak."   What are the best practices or published standards for dealing with the previous (really old) "foo.conf.bak" file?

I could rename it with some version or date number, I could over-write it, I could construct some more elaborate repository based solution to store all old versions, etc...  But what I'm looking for is some sort of standard practice to follow.

For this particular case, any sort of versioned repository solution would be way overkill.  Right now, mv'ing the previous ".bak" out of the way before creating my new one and making my edit to the live .conf file, seems like the best answer.

Comment: Since you don't care about old versions (otherwise you would be using a version control system), why don't you simply let the `.bak` file be overwritten?

Comment: That's likely what I am going to do.  I'm soliciting advice for "best practices" in such cases.  What's the norm of behavior here?

Answer (score 0):

The following is perhaps a good starting point, as it explains what one popular text editor (Emacs) can do as far as backup files are concerned: [How do I control how Emacs makes backup files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/151946/2808351)

In summary, without any special configuration, when one starts modifying file `foo`, a copy of its initial state is created as `foo~`, and any existing contents of `foo~` are discarded. That's probably good enough in many cases. Perhaps when one knows they're about to start a risky change, it's best to make copies by hand or use version control.

Comment: Thanks.  Emacs is a reasonable precedent, but I'm not sure it is *the* one to follow.  Let's see what the other Stack Exchange folks find.